# Making maths videos

Tags: soft-question

I have wanted to make math videos, but was never sure how to go about it. (Please redirect to the correct forum if this is wrong). I noticed how the khan academy videos are made on a computer, I would like to do the same thing with a software like LyX. But how would I capture the screen, and the voice at the same time?

I am on a Linux Machine but if there are solutions in Windows, please post them, others may be interested.

Edit: there has been a comment about this not being the right forum any suggestions? Also, I have come across other solutions on the internet, [recordmydesktop](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://recordmydesktop.sf.net/about.php&ei=bM6bTYa9M8m2tgeTt5nWBw&usg=AFQjCNEe3UyvyAMl9WmDIonEksaw0jYAaQ) came up. Has anyone tried it?

Comment: This probably isn't the right forum for this question. Screen capturing for videos and tutorials is most often done with Camtasia.

Comment: Capturing sound at the same time as you capture video can lead to bad videos, unless you have unusual talents. Edit heavily. I use Camtasia and Audacity on Windows.

Comment: @Douglas, can you explain what you mean. If the capture and the voice over is done at separate times, it would sound wrong to me, since you may forget what you intended to say when you were writing the formulas down. Am I right?

Comment: This is too far off-topic, as it has hardly anything mathematics specific. You could ask on SuperUser.com, or the Unix & Linux StackExchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a point and shoot camera and set it up pointing down. That's what I do on my blog.

Comment: Unless you show me a link about a video done this way, I will not know what you mean. Sorry.

Comment: I am guessing Bon Crowder is thinking something along the lines of [Vi Hart's vlog](http://vihart.com/)?

Comment: thanks for the post, that is not the type of video I want to make.